# Problems with js in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, codepen

I have a problem with javascript on Wordpress!

I have to insert in my theme this pen https://codepen.io/z-/pen/OBPJKK .

HTML and css work, the only problem to fix is with javascript.

I replaced "$" in the original JS with "jQuery" and I entered this script in Theme Option> Advanced > Code Fields > Space Before head area:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery('.single .fusion-post-slideshow li img').each(function() {
  var caption = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
  jQuery(this).after('<span>' + caption + '</span>');
  }); 
});
</script>
```

The problem lies in the inability to reproduce the onclick effect of the aforementioned pen.

When going to the url of the page http://www.goatsplan.com/goats-magazine/, Wordpress seems not to recognize JS, and it is as if no code has been entered. Please, how can I solve this problem and keep the same type of animation in javascript?

Thank you very much

Comment: [Doesn't work isn't a useful description of the problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/broken/). You also should provide a [mcve].

Comment: (And edit your title to be (a) LESS SHOUTY and (b) more descriptive of the actual problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".option").click(function(){
   jQuery(".option").removeClass("active");
   jQuery(this).addClass("active");

});
```

Just past the above jQuery in the Footer file/Template

Its working fine--> https://prnt.sc/r04jfi
  https://prnt.sc/r04jug

Comment: Thank you for your time! This is the URL http://www.goatsplan.com/goats-magazine/

Comment: Thank you my friend but It doesn't work!

Comment: did you added the jQuery code

Comment: add the above JQuery code  inside this $(document).ready(function() {
      -----------------------------------------
});

Comment: And also add add the code 'in the footer file

Comment: I added the code in Theme Option> Advanced > Code Fields > Space Before head area and as you can see in goatsplan.com/goats-magazine it doesn't still work. How can I do?

Comment: convert $ to jQuert-----------jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery(".option").click(function(){
   jQuery(".option").removeClass("active");
   jQuery(this).addClass("active");

});});

Comment: YOU'RE THE BEST! IT WORKS GREAT! You have been very kind, one of the few in this community!